# "Безплатний" або "Безоплатний"?... а може "Безкоштовний"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Яке із слів вживати для позначення продукту чи послуги, яка надається без грошової оплати?

Безплатний, безоплатний, безкоштовний або якийсь інший варіант.

Буду вдячна за розгорнуте пояснення.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

СУМ-20

> [Безкоштовний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=3276&page=132) а, е. Який не потребує коштів, оплати; безплатний.
>   *Навчання, одяг і харчі там [у школі] були безкоштовні* (С. Скляренко);
>   *Магазин пропонує майже 100 видів безкоштовних послуг* (із журн.).
>
> [Безоплатний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=3381&page=135), а, е. За який не платять; безплатний.
>
> [Безплатний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=3448&page=137) БЕЗПЛА́ТНИЙ, а, е. Який не оплачується, не потребує
>   оплати. *Не так легко було дістати безплатну путівку поза чергою й саме
>   туди, куди радила лікарка* (Ю. Яновський)

Всі три слова є повними синонімами ([Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)) і можуть вживатися як взаємозамінні.